# Helmholtz's "Ueber die Bewegungsgleichungen der Elektricität für ruhende leitende Körper" in English?

Tags: specific-reference, history

Is Helmholtz's 1870 paper "[Ueber die Bewegungsgleichungen der Elektricität für ruhende leitende Körper](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.1870.issue-72/crll.1870.72.57/crll.1870.72.57.xml)," *Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik* **72**:57-129 translated into English anywhere?
thanks

Comment: It has a text version, which Google Translate does work on. However, the combination of OCR errors along with the translation errors cause the result to be mostly unreadable.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has translated it because Helmholtz's theory described in this paper was the major competitor to Maxwell's in the 19th century.